# How do I scale my overlaped header proportional to my image when zooming in?

Tags: html, css, zooming, overlap

I positioned my header as an overlap on an image. But when I'm zooming in the header gets misaligned and doesn't scale proportional with the image. I tried using rm and vw units but the problem still persists, so I returned to px. The image scales to 100% width screen-size.

Here is a sketch of my problem.
[image]

```css
.image-area {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .text-area {
        margin-top: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .text-area h2 {
          text-transform: capitalize;
          font-size: 50px;
          margin-top: 20px;
          position: absolute;
          z-index:2;
          top:60px;
          left:200px;
    }
```

```html
    

<div class="image-area">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="text-area">
        <h2> HEADER </h2>
      </div>
      <img src="path_to_image/image.png" style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your margin in percentage.

```css
.image-area {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .text-area {
        margin-top: 10%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .text-area h2 {
          text-transform: capitalize; 
          margin-top: 5%;
          position: absolute;
          z-index:2;
          top:10%;
          left:20%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-area">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="text-area"> 
        <svg viewBox="-10 0 200 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <text y="20" font-size="smaller">HEADER</text>
      </svg>
      </div>
      <img src="path_to_image/image.png" style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your solution, it solves the alignment problem  but the scaling problem is still there.

Comment: i have updated code use SVG if you want to same font size for all screen